# ArcMap near table but with taxicab geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network, proximity

ArcMap 10.4.0.5524 for Desktop. No internet connection.

I have a shapefile with ~ 200,000 line segments that connect at the vertices to form a network.

I would like to generate a table with the 1000 nearest line segments to each line segment. In this case, near is the minimum distance traveled along the network to the center of each "near" line from the center of the line in question.

Alternatively, generate a near table with minimum taxicab distances from points (events located on the lines) on the network to the center of each line.

Any ideas?

If the "Generate Near Table" tool in ArcMap had a "Taxicab" method I would think that would be pretty close.

Unfortunately I do not have a license for the Network Analyst extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can do this with the methods outlined here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/find-and-plot-your-optimal-path-using-plotly-and-networkx-in-python-17e75387b873